# Restore SVN Repository backup

Tags: svn-repository

I am using repositoryhosting.com i downloaded my Project backup from it. I want to check backed-up data.

1. The file has .GZ extension. Extracting it generated .tar file.
2. The .tar file gave subversion.dump file upon extraction.
3. Now i am not able to extract it further.

I get the following error upon performaing #3:

> Cannot open file path\subversion.dump'
>   as archive

Please suggest how to proceed. Am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
svnadmin create directory/where/you/want/to/put/your/repo
svnadmin load directory/where/you/want/to/put/your/repo <subversion.dump
```

Comment: Any software requirement for this? i am using windows XP

Comment: Well, you definitely need SVN to extract an SVN dump. Otherwise there should be no other software requirements.